# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, types, tuples

I am making a dice simulator, and I was testing the aesthetics when I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jacob/Documents/Code/Test.py", line 22, in <module>
    for j in DiceSides[i]:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Here is my code:

```
Segments = {
0: '\t.-------.',
1: '\t|       |',
2: '\t|   O   |',
3: '\t|     O |',
4: '\t| O     |',
5: '\t| O   O |',
6: '\t| O O O |',
7: "\t'-------'"
}

DiceSides = (
(0, 1, 2, 1, 7),
(0, 3, 1, 4, 7),
(0, 4, 2, 3, 7),
(0, 5, 1, 5, 7),
(0, 5, 2, 5, 7),
(0, 6, 1, 6, 7)
)

for i in DiceSides:
    for j in DiceSides[i]:
        print(Segments[j])
```

I don't understand this `TypeError`, could someone explain to me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the *elements* of `DiceSides`:

```
for i in DiceSides:
```

`i` is *not an index* here, it is bound to the tuples of `DiceSides`. The `for` statement in Python is really a [Foreach loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), you get the actual elements from the iterable, rather than indexes into the iterable.

As such, because `i` is already a tuple, you can just loop over the value directly:

```
for i in DiceSides:
    for j in i:
        print(Segments[j])
```

An alternative spelling would be:

```
for i in DiceSides:
    print(*(Segments[seg] for seg in i), sep='\n')
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in DiceSides:
...     print(*(Segments[seg] for seg in i), sep='\n')
... 
    .-------.
    |       |
    |   O   |
    |       |
    '-------'
    .-------.
    |     O |
    |       |
    | O     |
    '-------'
    .-------.
    | O     |
    |   O   |
    |     O |
    '-------'
    .-------.
    | O   O |
    |       |
    | O   O |
    '-------'
    .-------.
    | O   O |
    |   O   |
    | O   O |
    '-------'
    .-------.
    | O O O |
    |       |
    | O O O |
    '-------'
```